# Is there a wrapper around Gmail tasks API?

Tags: gmail, google-tasks, google-api

I would like to write an app that displays and manages Gmail tasks.

There's a couple on Android but none on Windows Phone 7.  The Android ones are not open source and there's no official documentation for the API.  This'd mean I probably won't be doing this app as it'd involve a lot of time snooping around figuring out the API.

Does anyone know of a wrapper around the API or any documentation for it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485822/gmail-task-api-exist) there isn't currently an API for GTasks.